# What could be the source of my water leak?

Tags: water, leak

Before I go tearing up the side of the house, I wanted to ask if anyone else has experienced this or has advice. We got some rain yesterday and I just happened to be in our boiler room. There have always been signs of water leakage here but I thought they were years old and fixed.

Turns out, it has not been fixed and I saw water leaking in from the rain. My initial thinking is this problem stems from the flashing between the side of the house and the gravel ground. Maybe it's not long enough, deep enough, flush against the side of the house? Or there is a penetration somewhere? I can share pictures - just not sure how y'all prefer it to be linked/shared.

Am I on the right track? Or do y'all need more pictures to say one way or another?

What kind of professional do I call to take a look at this?

[image][image][image]

Comment: Foundation people will probably be the to seal the outside.  Do you have a good ground grade sloping away from the house and downspouts that drain far enough away?

Comment: Remember that water could be entering some distance from where you see it. If there isn't a clear crack it's coming out of, you may want to spend some time tracing it back

Answer (score 3):

Here's my learning on this:  waterproofing the foundation will be hit or miss.
If there is significant water on the outside, it will find a way in.

The best solutions are to get that water away from the foundation.  French drains, ditches, gutter downspout extensions, soil buildup, etc., depending on what you need exactly.  Unless you live in a desert there will be companies near you who specialize in this.  Youtube is filled with videos about yard drainage.